# How do I use one config key in another?

Tags: php, laravel-5

In Laravel 4's cascading configuration files I was able to reference one configuration key from another. For example, I liked to have `app.debug` set to true or false, and then I could switch error reporting to Sentry to the opposite of that in a different configuration file, by setting the relevant setting to `!Config::get('app.debug')`.

I knew this was a little hairy because presumably whether the config value can be found depends on the order in which files are loaded. But I managed to get it working each time.

I'm having no such luck in Laravel 5. I get a "class not found" error when I try to do `Config::get(...)` in a configuration file. Using the `config(...)` helper instead produces no error but the values aren't retrieved.

The convention, of course, is to use environment variables, the `.env` file and `env(...)` to grab the values. That way each configuration key can use the value of the environment variable. That's fine and works, but I have some values which are shared between environments, and I do want some of these values to be committed to version control.

Using the `.env.example` file isn't a good solution for me since I don't want to have to remember to copy values over to the `.env` file of each environment if they change.

How can I store some configuration values in a way where they are shared between environments, are present in version control, and can be referenced in multiple configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, which works, but I'm interested in other possibilities.

Add a new shared file, checked in to VCS, called `.env.shared`. Its structure is just like `.env`. Edit `bootstrap/app.php` to load in these variables (in addition to `.env`):

```
// Load shared environment variables
$app->afterLoadingEnvironment(function () use ($app) {
    Dotenv::load($app->basePath(), '.env.shared');
});
```

I added this right after `$app` is instantiated.